# decode json into php variables

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get the contents of a JSON result into php variables. The code I am using is:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=51.507351&lng=-0.127758&date=today"), true);
```

The output of the JSON call looks like this:

```
array(2) { 
     ["results"]=> array(10) { 
         ["sunrise"]=> string(10) "4:21:35 AM" 
         ["sunset"]=> string(10) "7:32:34 PM" 
         ["solar_noon"]=> string(11) "11:57:04 AM" 
         ["day_length"]=> string(8) "15:10:59"
         ["civil_twilight_begin"]=> string(10) "3:42:08 AM"
         ["civil_twilight_end"]=> string(10) "8:12:01 PM"
         ["nautical_twilight_begin"]=> string(10) "2:49:55 AM" 
         ["nautical_twilight_end"]=> string(10) "9:04:14 PM" 
         ["astronomical_twilight_begin"]=> string(10) "1:41:12 AM" 
         ["astronomical_twilight_end"]=> string(11) "10:12:57 PM" 
      } 
      ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" 
}
```

How can I get the "sunrise" time and the "sunset" times into php variables $SunRiseTime and $SunSetTime;

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: `echo json_decode($json,true)["results"]["sunrise"];` and `echo json_decode($json,true)["results"]["sunset"];`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43673876/6521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and straight.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$json = file_get_contents("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=51.507351&lng=-0.127758&date=today"); 
$array=json_decode($json,true);

echo $SunRiseTime=$array["results"]["sunrise"];
echo $SunSetTime=$array["results"]["sunset"];
```

**Output:** `4:21:35 AM` `7:32:34 PM`

Comment: perfect, thats just what I needed. Many thanks to all that replied.

Comment: @DCJones welcome ... :)

Comment: I will as soon the system will let me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use $$ to define a variable in php dynamic. If your want to static define a variable, directly assign the value to it.

dynamic,

```
$name = 'SunRise';
$$name = $array["results"]["sunrise"];
```

static name,

```
$SunRise = $array["results"]["sunrise"];
```

Comment: Why not just directly use `$SunRise`?

Comment: For this is maybe dynamic. if this is static you're right.

Comment: appears to be static

Answer (score 0):

```
$SunRiseTime = $request['results']['sunrise'];
$SunSetTime  = $request['results']['sunset'];
```